# programs or methods to review Internet browser applications for security

Tags: firefox, updates, audit

I've been tasked with doing a security review on a Firefox update, but we don't have any utilities that we can find.

How would we go about running a security review on Firefox before pushing it to the other computers on the network?

Comment: Risking to stating the obvious, but if you don't have experience in software security review it is unlikely that you would be able to find any security issues in such a popular open source application as firefox.

You can either trust the vendor, or hire someone with the know-how to perform the review.

Comment: @valentinas the sys admin got canned and we're on our own, and a lot of our required utilities depend on the latest Firefox.  the sys admin was the only one who knew the security review stuff.  we're kinda stuck until a new person comes in.  :/

Comment: Security review is very technical field, it's not something you can do just by following a manual or running a tool.

Comment: If you are bound by legislation to do a security review of that application - hire a IT security company to do that. If not, then just install it. It's firefox, it's highly unlikely that there's going to be anything wrong with it, as long as you get it from official source.

Comment: @valentinas yeah, that was my thought re: Firefox.  I was told to get it reviewed, but I'm fairly certain it can be deployed without any real security concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very much depends on what you mean by "security review".  From the comments I guess this was handled by a general sys admin rather than a specialist in the past, so it's perhaps likely that what you need is just a relatively high-level review.

The sorts of things you could check for relatively easily before sending out an update would be

- Malware.  Ensure that there's no known malware in the downloaded software.  Either by running your in-house A-V software against it, or perhaps using a tool like [Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/) to check against multiple engines.
- Checksums. Ensure that the downloaded software matches the checksums provided by the vendor, to indicate that it has not been modified in transit.  For firefox these can be found [here](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/)

Comment: your sums link for ffox 404s.

Comment: not for me it doesn't... goes here http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/ and seems to work ok..

Comment: That link works.  :)

Comment: @Rory this was satisfactory for my boss, and we used these suggested high-level reviews to check Firefox.  My boss then gave the order to deploy Firefox to all systems, so thanks for some high-level pointers!